# A Laravel post route is being reject as requiring a get

Tags: laravel, routes

I am using Laravel 10 and have the following route defined:

```
Route::post('bulkPromptsStore', [App\Http\Controllers\ImageCategoryController::class, 'BulkInsertImagePrompts'])->name('bulkPromptsStore');
```

and in a blade file I call this in the normal way via a form

```
<form name="app" action="bulkPromptsStore" method="post"
  enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

There follows a csrf field.

However when I press store I get the following error:

> The POST method is not supported for route admin.imageCategory.bulkAdd/bulkPromptsStore. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.

I don't get it as it is clearly marked as a post and I have double checked that there is not a duplicate route name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`action="bulkPromptsStore"` should be `action="{{ route('bulkPromptsStore') }}"` instead, if you wish to use the named route. I suspect your form is on a URL named `admin.imageCategory.bulkAdd/` and thus your action is being treated like a relative URL within that pseudo-directory.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="{{ route('bulkPromptsStore') }}" method="post"
  enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Use it like this. It will work. Also don't forget to use `@csrf` in form like this.

```
<form action="{{ route('bulkPromptsStore') }}" method="post"
  enctype="multipart/form-data">
@csrf


------ other codes ------

</form>
```